# Using Grep to use value as id

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using grep to remove an object from my array. It will work if the keys are the same, however I want it to remove from the array if it matches the value `myVar` (I'm using the value as it will be unique), but I can't get inside the object as I can only access the index.

How can I remove the object with any value of Paris,London contained in `myVar` etc from my array?

```
function myFunction(){
        var arr = [
          {country:"USA"},
          {country:"France"},
          {country:"England"},
          {city:"New York"},
          {city:"Paris"},
          {city:"London"},
        ];

        var myVar = 'Paris';//Change variable
        arr = $.grep(arr, function(data, index) {
           return data.GET_TO_MY_VALUE!= myVar;
        });
        console.log(arr);
    }
    myFunction();
```

Comment: What is expected output ? `{city:"Paris"}` ? Or `[{"country":"USA"},{"country":"France"},{"country":"England"},{"city":"New York"},{"city":"London"}]` ?

Comment: To remove the object containing Paris

Comment: Use Array.filter `arr = arr.filter(function(data, index) {
    return data.city != myVar;
});` For **contain**, use RegEx `var regex = new RegExp(myVar, 'i');
arr = arr.filter(function(data, index) {
    return regex.test(data.city);
});`

Comment: I don't want data.city though, what if I want data.country. It need to be be dynamic on the value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Return the `grepped array` from `function`

To have multiple conditions, use `||` operator.

```js
function myFunction(myVar) {
  var arr = [{
    country: "USA"
  }, {
    country: "France"
  }, {
    country: "England"
  }, {
    city: "New York"
  }, {
    city: "Paris"
  }, {
    city: "London"
  }];
  return $.grep(arr, function(data, index) {
    return (data.city && data.city != myVar) || (data.country && data.country != myVar);
  });
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(myFunction('Paris')));
console.log(JSON.stringify(myFunction('England')));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```